# Allow android app to download file from website which checks/excludes mobile browsing?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm currently developing an android app for personal use, which will scrape a website such as the following:
http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/l/led_zeppelin/stairway_to_heaven_ver9_guitar_pro.htm

In particular, the website has the following form:

```
<form action='http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tabs/download' name="tab_download" class="tab_downloadcl notebox">
                <div class="textversbox">
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='223796' id="tab_id">
                        <input type='hidden' name='session_id' value='SESSION_ID_HERE'>
```

Upon clicking the download button, the website constructs the following link:

```
Request URL:http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tabs/download?id=223796&session_id=SESSION_ID_HERE&token=TOKEN_VALUE_HERE
```

I'm not exactly sure where the token value is obtained from (I suspect a SWF file later found in the form). However, the download link seems to work on desktop by omitting this token.

However, the site is constructed in such a way that if I were to visit that website on mobile, clicking the download button redirects the user to the forums. The same thing happens if the user were to follow the link I construct.

Currently, I have an AsyncTask used to download the first link above and construct the appropriate URL, using Jsoup. It can be found here:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0])
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();
            // Scrape page for download form
            String download_url = "http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tabs/download?";
            Elements form_elements = doc.select("form.tab_downloadcl");
            Elements elements = form_elements.select("input[name]");
            for (Element em : elements) {
                if (em.attr("name").equals("id")) {
                    download_url += "id=" + em.attr("value") + "?";
                }

                if (em.attr("name").equals("session_id")) {
                    download_url += "session_id=" + em.attr("value");
                }
            }
```

I have tried just opening the link in a browser, which redirects to the forum. I have also tried constructing a DownloadManager.Request, which downloads a .bin file. Another approach was just to open the download link so that the user could click the Download button, which doesn't work.

Is there a way to work around this safeguard and obtain the file, and if not I'd be interested to know what the safeguards are prevent this.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be that the link is constructed with JavaScript. If the site works on desktop but not on mobile, you could try changing your user agent to one which a desktop browser would use (several mobile browsers as well as Jsoup support this), and see what happens. If you think the link is generated by a SWF file, why not try disabling flash, and see if it still happens ?

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks a lot! I error-checked through flash, javascript, cookies, and in the end it was the user-agent for a desktop browser. The problem I was having was that JSoup was expecting a HTML document. To avoid this, I had to call HttpConnection.Request.ignoreContentType(true), before calling execute().